# Question about factoring a quadratic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, factoring

I was wondering if someone could clear this question I had.

$$x^2+4x-21=0$$
Factoring it out:
$$(x+7)(x-3)$$
How does that mean that $x=-7$ or $x=3$?

How is it that we can just say "Alright, let's just forget one part of the equation $(x-3)$, and solve for $x$, or forget $x+7$ and solve for $x$," and it's going to hold true?

Thanks!!

Comment: Should it be $(x + 7)(x - 3) =0$?

Comment: Your question probably is $ x^2 - 4x - 21 = 0 $ . If not, then you factored it wrongly.

Comment: This is because $0\cdot \text{anything}=0$ so if $x-3=0$ we can forget the rest part $(x+7)$ because no matter what the value of the rest part is the value of the expression will be $0$.

Comment: Thanks to everyone, for all the comments and answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you probably meant $ x^2 - 4x - 21 = 0 $ as the equation $ x^2 + 4x - 21 = 0 $ does not have the factors you mentioned.

Now you have: $ (x+3)(x-7) = 0 $ . When the product of two numbers is zero, then either or both of them is zero, which means that,

$ (x+3) = 0 $, which implies that $ x = -3 $ , or $ (x-7) = 0 $ , i.e, $ x = 7 $ .

Comment: This may not be true if the domain has zero divisors.

Comment: Thank you Manish, I corrected it. It factors into (x-3)(x+7).

Comment: @user472288 I hope your problem is solved.

Comment: Manish, I was wondering if you could clear this up for me: It means that one part has to equal 0 like you described. But we have to plug in an $x$ that makes this true right? If we do, then say $x=3$ so that $(x-3)=0$. But then we have to plug into $3$ into the other side as well, to make it $(x+7)=10?

Comment: No, you don't need to plug in anything. You simply equate the factors with zero and get the corresponding values of $ x $

Answer (score 2):

solving $$x^2+4x-21=0$$ we get $$x_{1,2}=-2\pm\sqrt{25}$$ and form here we get.....
we get $x_1=-7,x_2=3$ so we have $$(x+7)(x-3)=x^2+4x-21$$

Answer (score 2):

Prove that if $ab=0$, then $a=0$ or $b=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The technical term is the **Zero Factor Theorem**. It states that if two (or more) numbers multiply to make zero, then at least one of them had to already be zero - in other words, if I multiply together a bunch of things that aren't zero, I can't get zero out.

In this case, factoring tells us that $x^2 + 4x - 21$ is the same as $(x - 7)(x + 3)$. So if $x^2 + 4x - 21 = 0$, then we know that $(x - 7)(x + 3) = 0$. By the Zero Factor Theorem, that means we have one of two situations: either $x - 7 = 0$ or $x + 3 = 0$. If $x - 7 = 0$, then $x = 7$. If $x + 3 = 0$, then $x = -3$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Given the level of the question and the tags on it, I of course answered under the assumption that we're looking exclusively at real or complex numbers.

Answer (score 1):

We have to be careful, in which domain we solve such an equation. For example,
in $R=\mathbb{Z}/4$ we have $2\cdot 2=0$, but none of the factors is zero.
In a field $K$ however we have that $ab=0$ always implies that $a=0$ or $b=0$.
Hence
$$
(x+7)(x-3)=0
$$
implies then that $x+7=0$ or $x-3=0$.

Comment: Aren't these terms called complex numbers?

Comment: No, the terms are called "linear factors" of $x^2+4x-21$.

Answer (score 1):

$x^2 +4x -21=0.$

$x^2 +4x -21 = (x+7)(x-3) =0.$

The product $(x+7)(x-3) = 0$

$\iff $

one of the factors

$(x+7)$ or $(x-3)$ is 0.

1) $x+7= 0$ gives $x=-7;$

2) $x-3 = 0$ gives $x=3.$

Note:

For real $a,b:$

$ab = 0$ implies $a=0$ or $b=0$.

('Or' means : One factor or the other or both)

Helps?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I learned it. Factoring an equation gives you the answers, as to where on the curve is $f(x)=0$. So when you factorize an equation, $x^2+4x−21=0$, you want to find which value of $x$ satisfies $f(x)=0$. In this case your equation was $x^2+4x−21=(x+7)(x-3)$. Then you consider each bracket separately, $x+7=0$ and $x-3=0$, $x_1=-7, x_2=3$. So your answers are $x_1=-7, x_2=3$. You can consider each bracket individually because if one of the brackets ends up as a $0$ then $f(x)$ will be $0$.